# discord.py invite by guild id in bot join

Tags: discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def serverinvite(ctx,guild_id : discord.guild.Guild.id):
    if ctx.author.id == 761156852276789248:
        server = bot.get_guild(id=guild_id)
        invite = await server.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite()
        e = discord.Embed(title="invite",colour=0x9E003A,description=invite)
        e.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
        e.set_author(name=bot.user.name, icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/967363930492108821/967499783692517466/sdsasa.gif?size=4096')
        await ctx.send(embed=e)
    else:
        pass
```

what wrong i want it send me invite to server

Comment: Hey hx, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include any error messages you are getting with this code as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

with id:

> ```
> ID = int
> guild = client.get_guild(ID)
> guildchannel = guild.text_channels[0] # get the first channel of the guild
> invitelink = await guildchannel.create_invite(max_uses=1) # create the invite link
> ```

with server name:

> ```
> servername = "str"
> guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, name=f'{servername}')
> guildchannel = guild.text_channels[0] # get the first channel of the guild
> invitelink = await guildchannel.create_invite(max_uses=1) # create the invite link
> ```